# Installing pcf fonts on Gentoo for urxvt and Awesome wm

Tags: linux, fonts, gentoo, awesome-wm, urxvt

I downloaded the linux version of Profont from [here](http://www.tobias-jung.de/seekingprofont/)

And I have no idea how to install it. I want to be able to use it for urxvt and awesome wm. What should I do?